# Azure Web-Role Kudu Remote Execution Console "tasklist.exe" returns nothing

Tags: azure, cmd, azure-web-roles, kudu

when i'm running the command "tasklist.exe" in the Kudu Web Frontend CMD it returns nothing, it seems that the process is hanging.

We need this command in our web application. Does anyone can confirm this or has a resolution ?

Our application runs on node.js (for information)

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffPIS.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. I have no resolution, but maybe a workaround.

Use the PowerShell console instead (same menu as the cmd) and the command `Get-Process`.

If you're missing properties in the default output, select the ones you need.

To see a complete output use `Get-Process | select *`. Look there for properties you need. The output could be a little bit confusing because there are so many properties.

If you know what properties you need, you could create a nice output. For example: `Get-Process | Format-Table Name, Handles, StartTime, Path -AutoSize`